# How to reference Foreign Key(s) to the parent table where data goes on increasing?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

Hello i am very new to learning PHP and MySQL. I have just begun learning MySQL. As the question mentioned above, will be kind if anyone can give a solution. Please see the example of a simple restaurant order below.

Table 1 (parent table)

```
id | username | city
1  | bob      | berlin
2  | sam      | stuttgart
```

Table 2 (child table where 'menu_id' is a foreign key)

```
id | menu_name | menu_id | order_date
1  | pizza     |   2     | 2016-05-04
2  | pasta     |   2     | 2016-05-04
3  | cookies   |   1     | 2016-05-03
4  | sandwich  |   2     | 2016-05-06
5  | cake      |   1     | 2016-05-02
```

Now by a simple 'LEFT JOIN' with 'ORDER BY order_date ASC' i can see in which dates which user ordered what.

But here is my question:

I have assigned the Foreign Keys manually, but suppose in the parent table more users are coming in then do i have to add Foreign Keys manually too? That will take a long time. Is there any workaround? And if there isn't then why use the Foreign Keys at all?

Comment: Your application "knows" who ordered the item, it knows which id it is, so it can fill in the `menu_id` value when inserting the row. You are not supposed to create the data manually (unless you do it for testing of course), you want to write the PHP code to do that automatically for you.

Comment: Many thanks for replying. Please forgive me since i have not yet learnt how to do it in PHP. But you are saying that it is possible to fill up the 'menu_id' with a new number by PHP code.

Comment: Yes. When you insert new row (representing new user as it seems) into the Table 1, you can use the `last_insert_id()` mysql function to get the id value generated for that new row (if you use auto_increment IDs in that table, if you don't then you already know the id value when inserting anyway) so you can use that number as the `menu_id` value when inserting new row to the Table 2. Any decent PHP+MySQL tutorial should cover that part :)

Comment: @AbhrapratimNag I think what you are looking for is the `auto_increment` property of a mysql column: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html and the usage of `last_insert_id()` function, which will remember for you the id of the "parent" table, and you can use it on (for example) a "child" table within a session (mysql connection): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html